# How to store data for website book gallery

Tags: javascript, database, local-storage

I'm trying to make a website where a user can look through an image gallery of books, each accompanied by the book's name and other properties, such as reading level, number of pages, etc.

I'd be using my own images of the books and entering the data for them myself, but I'm not sure how to store these book objects. I obviously don't want to manually make a `<div>` for each and enter all the data, but rather use JS to access the list of all the books and their data and output them.

I'm not sure what would be the appropriate method of storing these books. Would I make a SQL database, use localStorage, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure you do not want memory and performance to be a concern when you design something.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values) to know more about localstorage limitations.

I would suggest you go with a database and store it there, will be a scalable option as well. I am assuming you have a crud operation also involved in your website.